# FBconnect problem in cocos2d iphone?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, fbconnect

When i wrote this line then this code

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "FBConnect.h"
//Register the delegates with this layer


@interface GameLayer :CCLayer<FBDialogDelegate, FBSessionDelegate, FBRequestDelegate>
{

//******************************************************/
// This is the facebook session that we use to interface
// with facebook, EVERYTHING facebook related relies
// on this: Login, Publishing Stories, etc...
//******************************************************/
    FBSession *_session;// Error occur: 
}

//******************************************************
// Facebook notifications from MenuLayer to do the work
//******************************************************
-(void)LogOutFaceBook:(NSNotification *)notification;
-(void)LoginFaceBook:(NSNotification *)notification;
@end
```

This Error is appear :
error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'FBSession'

How can i resolve this? I connect FBConnect folder and FBConnect.bundle in my project.What will i do?

Comment: you can use [share kit](http://getsharekit.com/install/) in ur project, for dealing with fb

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
#import "FBConnect/FBConnect.h"
#import "FBConnect/FBSession.h"
```

If you keep the Command key pressed and double-click on FBSession, does it take you to the definition? If not, looks like you have not included the FBConnect files properly.

Ensure you follow all the steps mentioned on their github page properly.